# Meaning of flux 2-integral

Tags: general-relativity, definition, integration, vector-fields

Can someone please explain the meaning of flux 2-integral in this sentence:

> Mass is evaluated as a flux 2-integral at the asymptotic infinity.

For asymptotic infinity, I believe it is as explained in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/401260/) Math.SE post.

Comment: We will need a lot more context to answer this question, as far as I can tell a 2-integral may mean a double integral. This would fit with a flux integral being the double integral over the scalar product of a vector and an area element. But what it has to do with mass depends on the context...it has meaning in fluid dynamics where they might mean mass transfer rate through a cross sectional area.

Comment: Quote from which reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 2-integral means an integral over a two-dimensional hypersurface.

Flux means the “flow” of some quantity across this surface. Mathematically, you are usually integrating the components of some tensor perpendicular to the hypersurface.